# How do I get Ubuntu Snappy started using KVM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to get a virtual image of Snappy started using KVM.

```
Launch Snappy locally with KVM on Linux
```

Found a nice and simple howto [Launch Snappy locally with KVM on Linux](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#snappy-local)

Completed the following steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
$ kvm-ok
Command 'kvm-ok' is available in '/usr/sbin/kvm-ok'
The command could not be located because '/usr/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
kvm-ok: command not found
$ sudo kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
$ wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic.img.xz
$ unxz ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic.img.xz
```

So far so good till the next step came along.....

```
$ kvm -m 512 -redir :8090::80 -redir :8022::22 ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic.img
```

The following output presented itself:

```
(process:32493): GLib-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-Lm6jKr/glib2.0-2.45.7/./glib/gmem.c:482: custom memory allocation vtable not supported
qemu-system-x86_64: invalid host forwarding rule ':8022:22'
qemu-system-x86_64: Device 'user' could not be initialized
```

Who can show me how it's done from here?
I already tried searching [Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), and various other [piles of whisdom](http://www.google.com).
 I'm a bit stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

That's the error message you get if you mis-typed the redirection string.

If you really did  type "-redir :8022::22" (and not -redir :8022:22, or 8022::22) then it should work.